# Where can I find the AirPrint firmware update for my HP 8500A printer?

Tags: ipad, printing, airprint

I was excited when my new [HP 8500A](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=4083969&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en) arrived this weekend because I wanted to try out its recently added [AirPrint compatibility](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20025352-263.html). However, I can't seem to find the [requisite firmware update](http://www.hp.com/sbso/printing/mac/hp-airprint.html) for the printer. Since I haven't updated the firmware when I tap print from Safari I'm told no printer can be found. What am I missing to enable AirPrint on my HP 8500a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my question the printer requires a firmware upgrade to become AirPrint compatible. What is not clear on HP's [AirPrint website](http://www.hp.com/sbso/printing/mac/hp-airprint.html) is how one goes about updating the firmware. Playing with the menus on the printer I finally found that attempting to access the web apps menu causes the printer to check if it has the latest firmware. The printer then determined that it did not and proceeded to download and install the firmware update. After the update the iPad lists the printer as an option for printing. My programmer brain was probably making this too hard looking for a non-consumer friendly way of doing the update. That said can't say opening up the web apps menu is the most obvious way to check for a firmware update.

Comment: You have answered a question that the apple help line could not and the Mac expert and printer expert at best buy couldn't answer! I was about ready to trash my I-pad or 2nd printer or both!! Thanks!!

Comment: @Tab glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer a question with a question, but [are these the drivers you're after?](http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Lookup?h_lang=en&h_cc=us&cc=us&h_page=hpcom&h_client=S-S-R295-1&h_pagetype=s-002&h_query=Hp+8500A&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

If not have you followed the network setup for your printer (via your computer or the printer itself) and turned on ePrint / AirPrint?

Comment: I've donwloaded those. I figured this out last night and was just getting ready to post an answer.